# Why would Android file write or copy be delayed?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've an app which runs on Pico Neo headsets. I'm using Unity, just switched from 2019 to 2020 LTS.
I create log files, initially internally, in the /data/data/com.myorg.myapp/file folder, where I create a folder called 'upload' (and it appears instantly). On program exit, I copy files that I'd created in that 'upload' folder to a similar folder in 'sdcard/Android/data/com.myorg.myapp/files'. Where again, the folder does appear. However, the files themselves do not show up there, as examined by Android Studio or ADB.

That is until much later. Like hours later.

This problem seems to have started when we did the switch to Unity 2020 but I'm not sure if other code changes may have affected it, there are no code changes to the stuff that creates and writes and copies these files.

Has anyone seen this type of problem? What might be a cause? Any tips, even google search suggestions, would be appreciated.